# why does my tkinter interface not show when i run it on python

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code please help me

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
theLabel = Label(root, text='This is too easy')
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fix your formatting

Comment: On my end, a window appears. Your code is working. Maybe the window is on a different monitor? If you have 1 monitor, try https://support.ti.davidson.edu/hc/en-us/articles/115016089728-Move-an-Application-Window-From-Off-screen-Back-to-Your-Main-Desktop-Windows

Comment: What OS are you running on? What python version are you using? That is the output of: `from tkinter import TclVersion; print(TclVersion)`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me with python 3.8.9 on OSX.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with python 3.9.5 on Windows 10. I haven't tested it but I am 99% sure it will work fine on Python 3.9 Ubuntu 20

Comment: Works fine for me on 3.9.6 on macOS.

Answer (score -1):

Could be due to the fact that you missed a space when importing the tkinter module. Python will be really strict with those imports

Try changing

```
from tkinter import*
```

into

```
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Having that space is certainly good style, but if its lack was an actual problem, there would be a `SyntaxError` rather than the program just doing nothing.